# The *html files of rendered vignettes are too big for CRAN

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, r-package, cran

I'm cleaning up an R package in order to submit to CRAN, and I have the following note:

```
* checking installed package size ... NOTE
  installed size is 11.3Mb
  sub-directories of 1Mb or more:
    doc  10.1Mb
```

I invested a great deal of time in making three vignettes as R Markdown files `*.Rmd`, and it appears that the resulting HTML files are too large for CRAN. I'm reluctant to simply delete these, as it would be useful for these vignettes to be easily accessible for CRAN users.

Here is the header I'm using for the vignettes:

```
---
title: "The Title of the Vignettes"
output: 
  rmarkdown::html_vignette:
    toc: true
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{"The Title of the Vignettes"}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

The `knitr::rmarkdown` files are not a problem, but the `*html` files are too large.

What is the correct approach here? I don't think I can simply make R ignore these files via `.Rbuildignore`.

Are there other examples where this has been solved?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the large files? Embedded images? Or just very extensive documents?

Comment: @CL. They're both

Comment: @CL. I'm happy to share them with you, if you'd like. I suspect I'll just have to put the html files somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer here is that, there's nothing to be done.

In order to bypass CRAN rules, host the `*html` files elsewhere.

Comment: I prefer to host the `html` files on my own server anyway so that I can update them independently of package updates and so that I can use the `rmdformats` package `rmdreadthedown` output format, which makes even larger `html`.  I refer to the URL of the vignettes in the package `DESCRIPTION` file.